# Get a variable dynamically JSX

Tags: reactjs

How can I change className based on menu.level? I want to set a diferent style based on the `menu.level`, per example `className={classes.item1}` if level=1 or `className={classes.item2}` if level = 2;

```
 const styles = theme => ({
  item1: {
    background: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
  },
  item2: {
    background: 'rgba(235,0,0,1.0)',
  },
  item3: {
    background: 'rgba(215,0,0,1.0)',
  },
  item4: {
    background: 'rgba(195,0,0,1.0)',
  },
});

const MenuItem = (props: Props) => {
  const { menu, classes } = props;
  return (
    <ListItem
      button
      onClick={menu.show}
      key={menu.name}
      level={menu.level}
      className={classes.item1}
    >
      <ListItemText
        primary={`${menu.name.replace('\n', ' ')}  :${menu.level}`}
      />
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple check for menu.level value before assigning className should do it. Something like this

```js
const classSwitch = level => {
  if (level === 1) {
     return classes.item1;
  }
  // more conditions or just a switch statement
}
const MenuItem = (props: Props) => {
  const { menu, classes } = props;
  const listClass = classSwitch(menu.level); // <----- like this 
  return (
    <ListItem
      button
      onClick={menu.show}
      key={menu.name}
      level={menu.level}
      className={listClass}
    >
      <ListItemText
        primary={`${menu.name.replace('\n', ' ')}  :${menu.level}`}
      />
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Hope this helps.